# In yii how to send confirmation mail

Tags: yii

In yii i am creating registration module. After submittion of form,entries will get inserted into corresponding fields in user table. From server side,confirmation mail will get send to that user's email. so how to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check yii's default inbuilt mailer, which will give you the idea of how mail works, then check this [tutorial for mail](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/195/implementing-a-registration-process-using-the-yii-user-management-module/), you can use mail extensions of yii to send a mail check this [list of mailers](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?category=9).

Hope this will make you learn how to mail.

Thanks.